# search mysql database for value

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to search the database row by row for an IP address and for a poll number. They need to be on the same row (yes they are in their own columns).

If the IP address and poll are on the same page I would like to show some code. If not I would like to show a different set of code.

How do I go about searching the database row by row for matching IP addresses and poll numbers? Thanks.

P.S - yes there is an ID column in the database.

Comment: Post your table structure

Comment: use sql AND operator in sql WHERE clause

Comment: `SELECT something FROM sometable WHERE ip=$ip and poll_number=$poll_number`. But that's about all we can do since you've provided no useful specifics

Comment: YOu need to post more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the easiest way to achieve your task .

```
<?php
    $ip = '127.0.0.1';
    $pollNum = 3546;
    $query = mysqli_query($connection , "SELECT id FROM poll_table WHRE pollID ='$id' AND  ip = '$ip'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    # Found -> Execute a set of code 
    } else {
    # Not Found -> Execute a different set of code .
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: You forgot a quote in `$pollNum = '3546;` Notice SO's syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 1):

Usually with a SELECT-statement, i.e. if you search for IP-Address 172.0.0.1 and poll number 127:

```
SELECT
    ipaddress,
    poll_number,
    other_fields
FROM
    your_table
WHERE
    ipaddress = '172.0.0.1'    -- i.e your search value for the ip-address
AND
    poll_number = '127'        -- and your poll number
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all as it is now 2014, please use PDO to perform queries:

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=datebasename', 'username', 'password');
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "ERROR: ".$e->getMessage();
}

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE ip=:ip AND poll_number=:poll_number");
$stmt->bindParam(':ip', $ip, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':poll_number', $poll_number, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

if($rows){
    foreach($rows as $row)   
        print_r($row);
}
else
    echo "No results";
```